# Change the text of corresponding node with attribute's value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to change the text of corresponding node with attribute's value using jquery

```
<div class="rating">
    <h2 typename="First">One is First</h2>
    <h2 typename="Second">Two is Second</h2>
    <h2 typename="Third">Three is Third</h2>
</div>
```

to

```
<div class="rating">
    <h2 typename="First">First</h2>
    <h2 typename="Second">Second</h2>
    <h2 typename="Third">Third</h2>
</div>
```

Here I want to change the `h2` text with its corresponding attribute value `typename`. 
How to do so ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
​$(".rating h2").​each(function() {
    $(this).text($(this).attr("typename"));
});​​​​​​
```

Check working jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PTYZa/

Comment: While inspecting firebug an error as `illegal character $('.rating h2').each(function(){` .

Comment: I guess, you didn't add Jquery and it doesn;t recognize $ sign... Try to add Jquery before this.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.rating h2').each(function(){
$(this).text($(this).attr('typename'));
});
```

sugestion : Usage of data-attribute will provide more robust usage

```
<div class="rating">
    <h2 data-typename="First">One is First</h2>
    <h2 data-typename="Second">Two is Second</h2>
    <h2 data-typename="Third">Three is Third</h2>
</div>
```

now use data() function.

```
   $('.rating h2').each(function(){
    $(this).text($(this).data('typename'));
    });
```

see demo in [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zmTu6/)

Comment: I am getting error in firebug as `illegal character

$('.rating h2').each(function(){` .

Answer (score 1):

Use like this

```
$("[typename]").each(function(){
    $(this).text($(this).attr("typename"));
});​
```

Here's [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ranganadh/7x5hw/2/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.rating h2').each(function(){
    $(this).text($(this).attr('typename'));
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this I hope this is want you want to achieve [Demo on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jnJdt/1/)

```
$('.rating h2').each(function(){    
    $(this).text($(this).attr('typename'));        
        })
```